# IPython notebook directory traversal

Tags: python, ipython

A previous question, "Multiple directories and/or subdirectories in IPython Notebook session," asked about directory traversal. The answer given was that the feature is coming. I have also seen a command line flag that starts the server in a specific directory. I can no longer find this post. The flag is not mentioned in the official documentation.

What is this command line flag to set the working directory?

When can we expect to see directory functionality in IPython Notebook?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the flag you're looking for is `--notebook-dir=/home/foo/wherever`. I found this by running `ipython notebook --help`.

Navigating directories while the server is running is still 'coming', unfortunately. It's one of those things that will need to be done the right way, and the people who can do it (which doesn't include me) are rather busy.

Comment: I can only give my point of view but seeing as this flag exists I would think that most of us would be happy if the functionality of this flag were simply wrapped into the notebook. Give us a button that dynamically sets the directory. That is better than having to start or restart an instance of the server every time I change directories.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it is what it is. Thank you for the flag. I'll remember to try --help in the future.

Also, there is an example of how directories might be implemented. This hasn't made its way into the baseline so I'm not hopeful I could contribute by writing my own implementation.